# Javafx: Error resolving onAction // eventHandler not in the namespace

Tags: java, javafx

I am a complete beginner, messing around with javafx. My first try:
[FXML]

```
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="but0" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="146.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Handle" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button but0;

    @FXML
    private void Handle(EventHandler e){
        but0.setText("Bla");
    }
}
```

which results in the following error:

**Error resolving onAction='#Handle', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.**

Although my Controller class is clearly set as controller for the parent AnchorPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller needs to implement Initializable, like so: (this is just the NetBeans default FXMLController, I'm assuming you load it with  FXMLLoader.load() )

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable { // notice this


    @FXML
    private Button but0;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked the button!");
    }

    @Override // and this
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Also, methods should start with a lowercase letter, "handle" instead of "Handle" ;) while the second version works, too, it is not considered good style.

Comment: Thanks, worked. And I'll keep in mind to meet the regulations ;)

Comment: Nice, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of the handler method either needs to be a `Event` or it needs to be absent. The following 2 versions should both work:

```
@FXML
private void Handle(){
    but0.setText("Bla");
}
```

```
@FXML
private void Handle(ActionEvent e){
    but0.setText("Bla");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised i also imported the wrong EventHandler in another, more sophisticated project.

Comment: oh god, I just have an issue where an `onMouseClicked` handler over a `Pane` will not let my program run unless it accepts `ActionEvent` arguments instead of `MouseEvent` arguments, and yet the event itself won't work complaining about `argument type mismatch`... thanks for the clue, at least

Comment: @Xerz are you using the correct import for `MouseEvent`? If you're using awt's `MouseEvent` class instead of `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`: That's not a subclass of `javafx.event.Event` so `FXMLLoader` ignores methods taking this type of parameter.

Comment: @fabian I am indeed importing from `javafx.scene`, thanks